# Adding Widgets Underneath The Main Widget (Console) QT

Tags: c++, qt, widget

5 with a Macos and right now I have a central widget as a console screen. This shows output coming from my serial port functions.

Underneath, I want to add some other widgets that do other things, such as a button, slider, or lcd. I was wondering how one can do this.

The code that I currently have:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //******* Set up
    ui->setupUi(this);

    console = new Console;
    console->setEnabled(false);
    setCentralWidget(console);

    //create serialport object
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);

    //create settings object
    settings = new SettingsDialog;

    ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(true);
    ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(false);
    ui->actionQuit->setEnabled(true);
    ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(true);

    initActionsConnections();

    /************** Connection Events ***********************/
    connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this,
            SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));

    connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));

    connect(console, SIGNAL(getData(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(writeData(QByteArray)));
}
```

However, I want these widgets separate from the console screen, which is showing some output on its own. So I want to add the following widgets:

```
/************** Adding Widgets *********************/
//creation and attribution of slider
slider = new QSlider();
slider->resize(255, 20);
slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 255); //0-255 is range we can read

//creation and attribution of the lcd
lcd = new QLCDNumber();
lcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
lcd->resize(255, 50);

//layout with slider and lcd
main_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
main_layout->addWidget(slider);
main_layout->addWidget(lcd);

//***********some way add this main_layout underneath the console **********/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to set the centralWidget layout as a `QVBoxLayout` and add your items to the `centralWidget->layout()`.

The code in the `MainWindow' shoudl change somewhat like below.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

    console = new Console;
    console->setEnabled(false);
    // Add this line instead of setting your console as central widget.
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(Console);

    .... //Continue with rest of the things
}
```

Your code to add the extra widgets should look like this.

```
/************** Adding Widgets *********************/
//creation and attribution of slider
slider = new QSlider(this);
slider->resize(255, 20);
slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 255); //0-255 is range we can read

//creation and attribution of the lcd
lcd = new QLCDNumber(this);
lcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
lcd->resize(255, 50);

//Adding the widgets created to the main layout.
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(slider);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(lcd);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.